# timestamp conversion in databricks using date_format

Tags: sql, pyspark, databricks, aws-databricks

I would like to convert below timestamp in databricks, Please help to get desired format

```
select date_format(from_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp,'America/Los_Angeles'), 'MM/DD/YY HH24:MI') AS START_TIME
```

Error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: All week-based patterns are unsupported since Spark 3.0, detected: Y,
```

Comment: Try with this pattern `MM/dd/yy HH:mm`

Comment: Thanks Blackbishop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message you got:

> ***IllegalArgumentException***: ......, ***detected: Y***,

As described in [date_format() docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_format.html):

> ... for instance dd.MM.yyyy and could return a string like ‘18.03.1993’. All pattern letters of [datetime pattern](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) can be used.

[datetime pattern](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) lists valid symbols. `Y` is not a valid symbol. Use `y` instead.

It also says:

> Year: The count of letters determines the minimum field width below which padding is used. If the count of letters is two, then a reduced two digit form is used. For printing, this outputs the rightmost two digits....

So `yyyy` will give you `2022` and `yy` will give you `22`.